# XPS 8300 cannot find the new 3TB seagate hard drive

Tags: windows-7

I added 3TB Seagate hard drive to my a few years old Dell XPS 8300. Windows 7 took more than 10 minutes to start, but failed to detect 3TB Seagate hard drive. I saw many people here said 3TB Seagate shows 746GB or something, and then they may use "DiscWizard Software" as Seagate website mentions, http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/beyond-2tb/

But in my case, I could not see the new hard disk at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you see it under disk-management?

Comment: no. I cannot see it under disk-management.

Comment: Do other computer's or OS recognized the HDD? Give it a try if you didn't yet.

Comment: tried on Vista, but no luck.

Comment: So most probably your HDD had dead, but if its new and don't recognized just claim your warranty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to find a good solution for the "not recognizing more than 746.39 GB" issue myself.  As for your disk manager not seeing it at all, just make sure your drivers for the external case were loaded correctly, and then look to see if a drive does show up in the bottom section.  If it is there, but not populating in the top section, make sure it is set to a "basic disk" and not a "dynamic" or  "MBR" disk.